# Unable to run arch-specific checks with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am using a Raspberry Pi and wanted to compile `opencv` on it, then build the `.so` file and then re-install the pi and just use the `.so` file instead of having the entire 4Gb of `opencv` on the SD Card (since I'm just running code, not developing anything).

So I have one SD Card with the full 4Gb of `opencv` that I used to compile the `.so` file, on that system in my python script I can use `import cv2` and give the correct `PYTHONPATH` and it works just fine.

However, when I put my other SD Card in (with the exact same version of the OS, the cards were an exact clone before I installed `opencv`) I put the cv2.so in the directory of the python script and I run it with `import cv2` and I receive this error:

```
ImportError: cv2.so, Unable to run arch-specific checks
```

I don't understand this at all. Can I not do this with a `.so` file? It's the exact same Pi and OS so I don't understand where it runs into trouble with the architecture.

I read somewhere that compiling a static library `.a` might help, but I believe I would need to translate my code from python to C++, could that work perhaps?

I am using `opencv` version 3.1.0, and the latest raspbian jessie on a Pi 3.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What about this? http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28083/unable-to-run-arch-specific-checks

Comment: @Aidenhjj I will give it a go.

Comment: @Aidenhjj I have just noticed that the link only says he ran a fsck which turned out to be an unrelated issue to the arch error. It doesn't seem to have been solved on that question either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know how to fix that exact error, but I got OpenCV installed and running without issue using the following gist: https://gist.github.com/willprice/c216fcbeba8d14ad1138

I was not able to get it to run as a standalone include, however. I had to leave the entire library and IDE installed.